# Can I use window.open to open an existing php file and pass a javascript variables to that php page?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, window.open

I have some JavaScript variable in the parent browser window and now I want to open a new window(an existing php file) by clicking a certain button and pass those variable to the opened page. I know I can achieve that by GET method and I just wonder if there is a clearer way I can do it so I don't have to append the variable value at the end of the URL. I also searched on google and SO, someone suggested using window.opener somehow it seemed not to apply to php. I'm still a newbie. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

scripts in the opener page

```
var newWindow = window.open ("myfile.php" ,"_blank");
newWindow.var1="hello";
newWindow.var2="world";
```

myfile.php

```
//Is it possible to use the variables in php page as below?
window.opener.var1;
window.opener.var2;
```

Comment: Research the $_POST array instead of $_GET to avoid appending data to the URL string. Also, before anyone will post answers, you need to post what efforts you've made (ie: where's your coded attempt?)

Comment: This question is too vague. What are you trying to do? Why is appending variables to the URL a problem?

Comment: @colonelclick, the variable passed could be really long so I would rather avoid appending it to the URL if that's possible

Answer (score 2):

If you want those variables to be accessible to the PHP code, then no, the GET method is the easiest and most clear way of doing it.

```
No JS needed to open new window:
<a href="myfile.php?var1=foo&var2=bar" target="_blank">mylink</a>

JS method:
window.open("http://mysite.com/myfile.php?var1=foo&var2=bar");
```

myfile.php

```
<?php
    $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
    $var2 = $_GET['var2'];
    ...
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a form with POST method and `target="_blank"`, but other than that your options are limited.

People don't like popups anyway.